# Add word to user dictionary and retrieve them back from dictionary

Tags: android

I have few edittexts in my application where user enters company name, client name, purpose....kinds of things. Now I want to add those words to dictionary programmatically and thus they don't have to re-enter the whole word everytime, instead dictionary should suggest the word once they start typing.

I searched on the web regarding the same and I got something like

```
UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getActivity(), et_client_name.getText().toString(), 1, "", locale);
```

And we need to give two permissions to the app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
```

**But my problem is :** Once I add words using the above statement; how to retrieve it back from dictionary and suggest user as soon as user starts typing in.

Any help or reference to any good tutorials is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find solution of my question by my own....answering this question in the hope that it might help someone as a reference for the same kind of issue:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment implements TextWatcher {

    String itemClientName[] = {};
    ArrayAdapter<String> clientNameAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> clientNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AutoCompleteTextView et_client_name = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_client_name);
        getFromDictionary();
        suggestClientName();
        et_client_name.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void getFromDictionary() {
        System.out.println("Inside getFromDictionary");
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, UserDictionary.Words.WORD};
        cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                word = cursor.getString(1);
                // Prepare list for autoCompletion
                System.out.println("Inside prepareMyList" + word);
                if (!clientNameList.contains(word))
                    clientNameList.add(word);
                System.out.println("clientNameList::" + clientNameList);
                System.out.println("Word from dictionary is::" + word);
                // do something meaningful
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    public void suggestClientName() {
        String newAdd1 = et_client_name.getText().toString();
        if (!clientNameList.contains(newAdd1)) {
            clientNameList.add(newAdd1);
            // update the autocomplete words
            clientNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, clientNameList);
            et_client_name.setAdapter(clientNameAdapter);
        }
        // display the words in myList for your reference
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < clientNameList.size(); i++) {
            s += clientNameList.get(i) + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, it's really bad for responsiveness to query a `ContentProvider` from the main thread. You might get away with it sometimes on some ROMs, but you don't know how long it will take the user dictionary to reply to your query, and your UI is blocked until it does.

Comment: dude can you access the names from other places too? ex messages or viber etc?

Comment: To address Dan Hulme's comment, check out `LoaderManager`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html