# Android - how to create custom word dictionary for only my application?

Tags: android, spell-checking

I have successfully added a word to Android's predefined user dictionary, but i want to create a custom dictionary which can  only be accessed by my application.

For example: When i type "lol", the suggestions show me "laugh out loud" but when I want another meaning of "lol" then I can manually add another meaning of "lol" (eg, "xxxxxx" - so the next time the user writes "lol" in an EditText, the suggestions will show him "xxxxxx").

No other application should have access my dictionary data.

I have worked with spell checker class but it gives me only correct word and I can't my own word meanings.

Please give me some suggestions or links.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Androids inbuilt class UserDictionary so that you can add your spells programmatically into that, Here is a link you can go through with , and which may relates to your problem .(In this solution nidhi has manged programmatically to retrieve data back)

[Add word to user dictionary and retrieve them back from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122372/add-word-to-user-dictionary-and-retrieve-them-back-from-dictionary)

In addition you can go through following links to :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html

Moreover if you want a custom personal dictionary then manually you have to store words and retrieve them back .

Hope that helps !!!

Comment: thank you for this answer. but it will be there in all other application and i dont want that i want to add word for only my application

Comment: In that case you have to create your own keypad for your app , and then you can do whatever things you want with EditText in that keypad (Store and retrieve words from your own DB ) http://code.google.com/p/nethack-android/

Comment: Anything changed about this? enriching the dictionary for only a specific app is indeed a use case. Some apps have a different context and do not merit polluting the global dictionary, thus avoiding awkward spelling suggestions / typeaheads for other apps...